# What's a good open source django project to learn from?

Tags: django

What is a good django open source app that I can learn from?  Something that follows best practices, and covers the majority of features and isn't overly complicated?

Comment: what is your current familiarity with Python?

Comment: This is more of a forum-type question. You should consider asking it elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Well designed Django example code to learn from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540482/well-designed-django-example-code-to-learn-from)

Answer (score 5):

This would depend on your current level of knowledge of python and django.
If you are just starting to use django, I suggest you take a look in [django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/). It is well specified and clear. If you have some project in mind, start working on it while looking up for best practices about specific parts. For python coding style try to follow the [pep 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.

If you already have done some work with django there are many sites lie these:

- http://djangopackages.com/categories/apps/
- http://www.django-apps.com/

What I do nowdays is look into django contrib apps (admin, auth, comments, flatpages), which are built based on the rest of django. This gives the best ways on how to write my apps.

Following the django comments framework (object independent), I am working on an app [django-valuate](http://code.google.com/p/django-valuate/) (object independent attachment of ratings, likebuttons etc. through template tags)

These are some of my views. I have also *starred* this question, as I would like to know about some different perspectives and if mine are sound.

Answer (score 1):

I've found djangobb (www.djangobb.org) to be a complete application, production quality and relatively simple. I use it as a base for my application which has nothing to do with forums and bb.
cloc output: only 3000 lines of python code in 30 files, another 2900 lines of templates html

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there would be any one specific app that would cover all/most features of Django since the concept of the Django app itself is to perform specific/related functionality.

Having said that, a popular Django app is [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/). Its popularity stems from the obvious requirement of most webapps to have [User authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) and also its extremely easy to integrate with a Django project.

The best approach perhaps would be to keep trying the tons of open source Django apps available on the net. You can browse through http://www.djangopackages.com/ and http://www.django-apps.com/ to start getting your hands dirty.

Answer (score 0):

**[snipt.net](http://snipt.net/)**, a code sharing site:

https://github.com/lionburger/snipt

**[Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org)**, a code review web app

https://github.com/reviewboard/reviewboard/tree/master/reviewboard

**[rietveld](http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/)**, another code review on app engine, by GVR himself.  You need to know a bit of Django before digging into this source code since the Django models don't work on App Engine, GAE db model is used instead.

http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk